# Passing data from Main Window to page

Tags: wpf

I have created a ribbon (R:ribbon) inside my main window in WPF. And I added a frame to the same window (bottom to the ribbon) and display pages inside the frame according to the  buttons click on the ribbon.

1.I have ribboncombobox on the ribbon , I want to get particular value in that combobox and display that value in a page that is display in the frame.

2.Also need to transfer data from one page to another.

This is **window based project**. Don’t know is this possible to do. If it is possible please guide me with some sample code. If this concept is wrong please let me know how to do this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Have a ViewModel class for the MainView. Create properties for the corresponding data to be transferred and bind them.

Comment: Hi Veer,

Really appreciate your quick reply. As I really new to WPF I would appreciate if you could bit expain this to me, or send me a link that I can reffer. 
Thanks.

Comment: check this video by Jason to know about the MVVM pattern http://www.lab49.com/files/videos/Jason%20Dolinger%20MVVM.wmv Let me know if it helps.

Comment: The link is dead by now. Here's the [wayback machine link](http://web.archive.org/web/20101011001707/http://lab49.com/files/videos/Jason%20Dolinger%20MVVM.wmv)